# What does "F1" key do and how to use it to spread units?

Tags: starcraft-2, keyboard

Somewhere I read that <kbd>F1</kbd> helps to spread units from stack in different locations. I've tried to do that, but was not successful. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The <kbd>F1</kbd> key is used to select idle workers.

Recently people have used this as a trick to spread up workers under attack from various harassment:

1. Select your workers (box or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> click one)
2. Hit the stop key (usually <kbd>s</kbd>)
3. Hold down the <kbd>F1</kbd> key
4. Right click to various parts of your base

Because pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> only selects one worker at a time, and because giving a worker a move order makes it no longer idle (thus not selected by <kbd>F1</kbd>) this causes your workers to each move to a different point as you right click.  For maximum spread you can even right click in a circle.

Comment: Quick Tip: using Ctrl-F1 will select _all_ idle workers, you can use this to send them back to work easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what means "Click in a circle"?

Comment: I don't think this will work after patch 1.2 (you will need to repeatedly press F1 instead of holding it down)

Comment: @Budda, move your mouse in a large circle around your base while right-clicking

Comment: @Juan -- isn't the current patch 1.3 already?

Comment: @Raven the current patch is 1.1.3 -- 1.2 is on the PTR and will be released shortly. *<Edited by Juan Manuel>*

Comment: @Juan: That depends on what will be in patch 1.2. Currently it [doesn't](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/1306100875) look like the patch would affect this.

Comment: @sth, the change was roll-backed, so you are right. You can disregard my first comment